# Silverlight: How do I determine how my control got the focus?

Tags: silverlight

Specifically, I want to know if the control got the focus because the user tabbed to it or because the user clicked on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was thinking about this. While I don't have a bold answer for you, I was thinking of a few ways to do it. The problem, as you know, is that the KeyDown and MouseLeftButton down events happen after GotFocus. I also couldn't find a way to check the state of the mouse and keyboard during the GotFocus event.

You could add a new TabFocus and ClickFocus event and fire them off on the click or tab event.

On your gotFocus event, set a flag on the userControl.

justGotFocus = true;

add events
public event TabFocus, ClickFocus (metacode)

And then in the Mouse and Key events, you

TabFocus(this, new EventArgs())

ClickFocus(this, new EventArgs())

or just call a central function with a FocusType parameter

public event SpecificFocusEvent
SpecificFocus(this, FocusType.TabKey)

Sorry... tired... horrible code =P

You could put the above into an attached property to reuse.

OR
there's a flag somewhere I haven't found yet =P

pj

**EDIT**

You are on the right track, just a little out of order. Set the flag on the MouseDown events, read it with GotFocus, and clear it in MouseUp/GotFocus/LostFocus. It is ugly as hell, but but it usually works.

Comment: I haven't tried it for other controls, but for a TextBox the it turns out that the event order is MouseDown, GotFocus, MouseUp.

Answer (score 0):

By Control, do you mean a UserControl?

If though, the event GotFocus of the UserControl is raised when a (input)control, like TextBox on the UserControl gets focus.

The UserControl by itself cannot have the focus (by clicking on the background of the UserControl).

Comment: UserControls certainly can have the focus. All you need to prove this is to set IsTabStop=true and tab into it.

Comment: @Jonathan Allen: Thanks for the hint with IsTabStop. I didn´t konw that. Also i misread you question, so my answer isn´t useful.